# Applescript, trimmed quicktime video but can't keep file name and save

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I have tried for the life of me and I cannot figure out how to maintain the file name and "save as"

I have

```
tell application "Quicktime Player"
    activate
    trim document 1 from 20 to 50
end tell
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can give this a try.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
activate
tell document 1
    trim from 20 to 50
    save as file_name
end tell
end tell
```

Or...

```
close saving yes
```