# Trying to open, modify, and save files in Quicktime with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I am unsuccessfully trying to use AppleScript to automate the process of making small edits to a bunch of files. More specifically, I want a script that will:

1. Open a specific file in QuickTime
2. Split it into segments of a specified length
3. Save each segment as an individual file in the same format and with the same quality as the original.
4. Close the document

Most importantly, I want the script to essentially work unassisted/unmanned.

Here's some more info on what I'm trying to do: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100305070247890.

Another user on StackOverflow [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255876/applescript-trimmed-quicktime-video-but-cant-keep-file-name-and-save) a while back, but the suggestion does not work.

From the few online discussions I've been able to find, it appears that Apple took away some of the functionality of QuickTime after version 7. I'm currently using 10.3+

[Here's another discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/batch-trim-qt-files-by-set-amount.1050971/page-2) that describes almost exactly what I'm trying to do. As "kryten2" points out, export no longer seems to work in the new version of QuickTime. And, just like "VideoBeagle", I get permissions errors when I try to call the save method.

The code posted by VideoBeagle on that page does not work for me. Here's a modified version:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    open basefile --argument passed to script when executed

    set the clipboard to "outputfile"
    delay (0.25)
    tell document 1
        trim from 0 to 60
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "QuickTime Player"
                keystroke "s" using command down
                keystroke "v" using command down
                delay 1
                keystroke return
                delay 3
                #click menu item "Save..." of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            end tell
        end tell

        close saving no

    end tell
end tell
```

The code above DOES open the file in QuickTime and trims the file to the correct length, but then it creates an unsaved copy of the file in a new window, closes the original, but does not save the new document. When I experiment with the delay and remove the "trim" function, it will show the Save dialog but won't actually save a file.

Has anyone successfully managed to use AppleScript and QuickTime to save files? ...recently?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best should be to use export function of QuickTime Player 7 if you have the QuickTime Pro authorization (not free, but very cheap). to do so, you also need to download this old QT version from Apple site. it is still available, but Apple promotes the QuickTime Player 7 with basically only read functions.

Still if you want to stick to QuickTime Player (after version 7), there are known issues in scripting while saving. The workaround is to simulate part of GUI as you already start doing.

The script bellow asks for movie file to be processed, defines the new path and name for the modified video, trim from second 2 to second 6 and then use the GUI interface to save and close. I made many comments to make sure you can understand and update for your own needs :

```
-- select file to be processed
set myVideo to choose file with prompt "Select video to be processed"

-- set new path and file name
set newPath to ((path to desktop folder from user domain) as string) & "Test_Folder"
set PPath to POSIX path of newPath
set newName to "cutVideo.mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
activate
open myVideo
set myDoc to front document
trim myDoc from 2 to 6  -- keep only video from second 2 to 6
end tell
tell application "System Events"
tell process "QuickTime Player"
    keystroke "s" using {command down}
    delay 0.8
    keystroke "G" using {command down} -- go to
    delay 0.8
    keystroke PPath -- folder path with / and not :
    delay 0.8
    keystroke return
    delay 0.8
    keystroke newName -- fill file name
    delay 0.8
    keystroke return -- ok save dialog
    delay 0.8
    keystroke "w" using {command down} -- close window
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, pbell!
I've been reluctant to go back to QT7 because the users on the forum thread I posted were unsuccessful in their experiments with it.

Simulating the GUI just seems like it's such a hairy, sometimes inconsistent, way to do this (but it may be the only way). I was able to get your code to work (thanks!), though I had to add a delay after the trim... I'm assuming that the menu items had not been re-enabled quickly enough and QuickTime wasn't accepting the "s" keystroke.

Comment: I am pleased that it solves your problem. I tried many other ways to avoid QT GUI for save and export, but always failed. In GUI scripting, the required delay comes from the speed of the hardware,OS version and also if other processes are running in background.  This is why it is better to set safety high value....

Comment: I have to admit that after another hour of playing with the code you provided, I have not been able to get it to consistently perform correctly. I suspect/assume that is because of the factors you mentioned (hardware, processes, etc). Sometimes it doesn't activate the QT window, so the keystrokes get sent elsewhere (calling `activate` after `trim` _seems_ to fix this..??), sometimes the `keystroke newName` doesn't happen so the file gets named as "Untitled", etc. UGH! I may have to just increase the delay size and monitor the newly saved files as it's working. Thanks again!

Comment: Start with worth case and set delay of 2, then you should be able to see all steps on your screen. Of course, keep in mind that because you're using GUI scripting, you should not touch your keyboard or mouse during the run ! The script is working perfectly for me. Last, but not least, do you have the folder 'Test_Folder' created on your desktop (see line 4 of the script) : it must exist (or you can change the line in the script)